# output columns as an array for inarray checking

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

The following code works. However I was wondering if there was a way to clean up the top part where the columns are outputted as an array.

I didn't include the full script because it is too long, but basically I have three different queries and I want to match the values from the table `(resultInput...textarea...images)` with the editable values I defined.

In order for me to do this I need to have the columns outputted as an array.

I was wondering if there was a cleaner way of doing this? `(top-part until //end output as array)`?

```
    $ArrayResultInput = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultInput)) {
        $ArrayResultInput[] = $row['Field'];
    }
    $inArrayResultInput = $ArrayResultInput;
    //
    $ArrayResultTextarea = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultTextarea)) {
        $ArrayResultTextarea[] = $row['Field'];
    }
    $inArrayResultTextarea = $ArrayResultTextarea;
    //
    $ArrayResultImages = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultImages)) {
        $ArrayResultImages[] = $row['Field'];
    }
    $inArrayResultImages = $ArrayResultImages;
    // end output as array
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultUpdate)) {
        foreach ($row as $fieldname => $value) {
            if (in_array($fieldname, $inArrayResultInput)) {
                echo '<div class="wrapper"><label>' . ucfirst(str_replace('_', ' ', $fieldname)) . '<br><input name="' . $fieldname . '" type="text" class="input" value="' . $value . '"><br></label></div>';
            }
        }
        foreach ($row as $fieldname => $value) {
            if (in_array($fieldname, $inArrayResultTextarea)) {
                echo '<div class="wrapper"><label>' . ucfirst(str_replace('_', ' ', $fieldname)) . '<br><textarea name="' . $fieldname . '">' . $value . '</textarea><br></label></div><script type="text/javascript">CKEDITOR.replace(\'' . $fieldname . '\',{toolbar:\'Basic\'});</script>';
            }
        }
        foreach ($row as $fieldname => $value) {
            if (in_array($fieldname, $inArrayResultImages)) {
                echo '<div class="wrapper"><span class="form-file">' . ucfirst(str_replace('_', ' ', $fieldname)) . '</span><input id="' . $fieldname . '" name="' . $fieldname . '" type="input" class="input" value="' . $value . '"><input type="button" value="Browse" onclick="CKFinder.popup(\'../\', null, null, SetFileField_' . $fieldname . ');" class="button browsebttn medium"><br></div><script type="text/javascript">function SetFileField_' . $fieldname . '(fileUrl){document.getElementById(\'' . $fieldname . '\').value=fileUrl;}</script>';
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you using 2 names for every array? If you want `$inArrayResultInput` just call it that. By the way, the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and if you switch to for example PDO, you can get a whole result-set in your variable using `fetchAll`, no loops needed.

Comment: thanks man :) i still have to learn the new sql functions

Comment: This could probably be done cleaner in the mysql query. Can you post those as well? Perhaps this can be cleaned up with left outer joins.